# getSystemService is unable to be called in Android Studio

Tags: android

I wanted to call the getSystemService of AudioManager class this way

```
package com.example.android.miwok;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.media.AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN;
import static android.media.AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS;
import static android.media.AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT;
import static android.media.AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK;
import static android.view.View.GONE;


public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = WordAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private int mColorResourceId;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;

public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words, int 
colorResourceId) {

    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
.
.
.
}
```

the system said it cannot resolve method "getSystemService". Based on my understanding it cannot find the method. I tried adding 'this.' before the method, I still can't find the method. I tried changing the WordAdapter class to private or protected, but it wasn't allowed to do so.
Any help or clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: make an instance variable of context and call `context.getSystemService()`

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I'm rather new to android programming and java, can you clarify what is the "instance variable of context"?

Comment: I made an example as answer..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs it seems like the mAudioManager you created called the mContext variables from the outer class which creates NullPointerException. I tried to run the code and the log said I have an error in the line where I declare mAudioManager.

Comment: please update your post with your current code and error stacktrace....and please show the exact place where you create AudioManager...

Comment: I guess your nullpointer is because you haven´t initialized the context, or you are creating the audiomanager before you initialized context.

Answer (score 0):

Make an  instance variable of `Context` and initialize this in your constructor:

```
private Context mContext;

public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int 
colorResourceId) {

    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Then you can call the system service from `mContext`:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```